# Django - Accessing Model Field in class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title2 = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default=timezone.now)
    content2 = models.TextField(default=timezone.now)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics')
    post_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='post2_pics')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this function based view that uses the model:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'front/front.html'
    context_object_name = 'listings'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        check_for_zipcode = #where I want to access the author for the current instance 
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['zipcodes'] = check_for_zipcode
        return context
```

All I want to know is how can I access the `author` field in the class-based view. I can access the author in my HTML like so"

```
{% for listings in listings %}
  
  <h3>listings.author</h3>
    
{% endfor %}
```

With this, I'll get back the `author` field for every instance of that model.

How would I get the author for the instance in the variable `check_for_zipcode`? I tried `self.author`, `self.listings.author`, etc; but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

In `get_context_data` method you have the `object_list` which is the result of `get_queryset` method. So you can override the `get_queryset` method. You can even do the same in `get_context_data` in `object_list`. Sample example as below:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.all().annotate(zipcode=F('author'))
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for listing in listings %}
  
  <h3>listing.zipcode</h3>
    
{% endfor %}
```

This returns the id of author object since it is a foreignkey. If you want some other attribute like `username` then do `author__username` in the annotate function.